# Почему по адресу ххххх.ru не могу попасть на сайт а по IP заходит

Tags: http, centos

Подскажите, почему по адресу ххххх.ru не могу попасть на сайт, а по IP заходит; работало--работало и пропало.
 Выход в сеть идет через роутер dir 615, а так все работает

Comment: а     nslookup -type=any ххххх.ru что говорит?

Comment: а что значит "не могу попасть"? этой фразой очень многое можно обозвать.  может кривой днс, может у Вас кривой днс, может домен закончился, может кривые насройки вебсервера на сайте... да что угодно по вашему вопросу подходит)

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю в качестве DNS прописать 8.8.8.8 и 8.8.4.4 (сервера гугла) и проверить.Если не помогло - глянте какие NS сервера прописаны у регистратора доменного имени через сервис Whois (например [www.nic.ru/whois/?query=xxxxx.ru)](http://www.nic.ru/whois/?query=xxxxx.ru)) либо они там прописаны неверно, либо ошибка в работе самих NS серверов (Например неправильная настройка)

Answer (score 1):

В настройках маршрутизатора пропишите DNS вашего провайдера.

Answer (score 1):

DNS прописывается в:

```
nano /etc/resolv.confnameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Больше ничего не нужно...

Answer (score 0):

Наверное, истек срок регистрации доменного имени ххххх.ru...

А что говорят ping и traceroute на ххххх.ru?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно у провайдера проблемы с `dns`, или на роутере проблема с `dns`